# Python code different interpreted in Windows Linux

Tags: python-3.x

I got some code from a developer. This code is written in Python.  On Windows it works well. On Linux I have most work merged but I stuck with this line:

```
new_log_entry = f"\"{str(prompt).replace("\"","'")}\";\"{json.dumps(chat_response.json()).replace("\"","'")}\";\"{expected.replace("\"","'")}\";\"{id.replace("\"","'") if got_function_call else (id+'-will-retry').replace("\"","'")}\";\"{self.model.replace("\"","'")}\";\"{json.dumps(log_function).replace("\"","'")}\";\"{instructions.replace("\"","'")}\"\n"
```

I think it have to be something with the quotes but whatever I try Python nags around.

Comment: what is the behaviour you got? what is the one you wish for? maybe a `\n` vs `\r` issue?

Comment: Use a backslash (\) before each double quotation in the f-string to escape them rather than replacing them with single quotes. By doing this, Python is instructed to treat the double quotation as a literal rather than a string terminator.